# Controlling 10k ohm digital potentiometer IC using NI DAQ USB6001

Tags: spi, digital-potentiometer, daq

I am totally new to the DAQ system; used to work on Arduino.

For the requirement of a project, I have to control a digital potentiometer of 10k ohm (AD5245) using **NI DAQ USB 6001.**

- How do I interface Labview with this chip?
- Is there any library that I can use to communicate and control the digital potentiometer using the USB6001?

Answer (score 1):

USB6001 doesn't have hardware support for I2C.  https://forums.ni.com/t5/Multifunction-DAQ/Using-USB-6001-to-implement-SPI-I2C/td-p/3873084?profile.language=en

I2C isn't tremendously easy to bit-bang, either, because of bidirectional data and clock lines, and clock stretching.

Wrong tool for the wrong job.  If you're stuck with the USB6001, I suggest matching it to an SPI digital pot.

If you're stuck with both the USB6001 and the I2C pot, my recommendation for robust and fast development is to use the USB6001 to talk to a microcontroller via UART, and use the microcontroller to talk to the pot.

Answer (score 0):

If your using the Eval board, you won't be able to control it with NI (and I couldn't even get their software to work, so don't buy the Eval board. They don't provide the source code for the CPU either so the Eval board is useless.

The chip uses a SPI protocol, and you'll need to have an interface and program the internal registers yourself. This USB to SPI converter might be useful:
http://www.ni.com/en-vn/support/model.usb-8451.html

Comment: that IC uses I2C not SPI

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it'll be better to learn how to put out an I2C signal with that USB6001, then you can use it for other ICs with I2C interfaces, as well as the AD5245.

Controlling that IC does not seem to be too hard, once you figure out how to make the USB6001 put out an I2C signal. You just need to send two bytes to the IC, the instruction byte + data byte and the value of the potentiometer will change.